# Start Web Service in Solution without Web Reference

Tags: visual-studio, wcf

When I work with a web service in Visual Studio and I'm using a web reference, the WCF web service project is automatically started as soon as I start the client application. Interestingly, this does not change when I remove the web reference.

Is there a setting in Visual Studio to get this behaviour, without actually referencing the service? (I'm working with a [WebChannelFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908674.aspx).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the solution's properties, under `Common Properties`, `Startup Project`, you can choose `Multiple startup projects` and select `Start` as the action for both the service and the consumer.